# Image path in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, email, xamarin.forms

I want to send a mail in xamarin.android.I can send as text with the code below without image but the problem occurs when i try to send with an image as logo. I mean, i can't find the path of the image.

My sending mail method is:

```
public static void SendMail(List<string> to, List<string> cc, string subject, string body,string mfrom)
{
    string messageHeader = "Android E-Mail Testi";
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress(mfrom);
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to[0]));
    msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc[0]));

    var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource("Drawable://logo.png");//This path is not working.
    inlineLogo.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    msg.Body = string.Format(@"<img class=""img-responsive"" src=""cid:{0}"" style=""width:25%; float:left""/>
                              <br/><br/><h3>" + messageHeader + @"</h3>" + body, inlineLogo.ContentId);

    var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, "text/html");
    view.LinkedResources.Add(inlineLogo);
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(view);

    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xx.xxx.x.xxx");
    msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;


    List<MemoryStream> mStreams = null;

    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    smtpClient.Send(msg);

    if (mStreams != null)
        foreach (MemoryStream mStream in mStreams)
            mStream.Close();
}
```

I can send mail by using this code in asp.net.Only difference is file path. I used it like that and it works for web development:

```
var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/logo.png"));
```

Which method should i use for image(logo.png) path in xamarin?

```
var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource(???);
```

I don't know the real path.How can i reach the path of the image in the drawable folder of the Resources folder?

Directory is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help you. I created ToolbarItem with icon from the same folder Resources/drawable in such way:

```
    new ToolbarItem("ToolbarItemName", "iconName.png", () => { //Some action; })
```